# Enabling pause button in windows 7 copy dialog

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer, dialog

Today, while sniffing around with Spy++, I found a hidden pause button in windows 7 copy dialog box.[image: Hidden "Pause" button...]

Is there any way to enable it like a registry tweak or something?